# JCrop php script

Tags: php, jquery, jcrop

I'm using JCrop in my website project and I have the form to upload the cropped photo using php but I have no idea how to actually send the "cropped" area through php. I have a upload script that is fine for the actual upload but how do I crop the Co-Ordinates of the cropped image? Are there any resources out there to outline this?

Comment: Please add some code to your question!!
Copy parts of images using `imagecopy()` - http://php.net/imagecopy

Comment: Please check my answer. If it's useful, set the answer as accepted or vote it up. Otherwise just write what's missing in the answer or what are the problems you're dealing with now and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the demo available @

http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler

to see how to get the coordinators / dimensions to send to php via a form submit or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

To get crop coordinates from Jcrop, you need to use *tellSelect()* method. Then you can send these coordinates to your PHP script (e.g. via an ajax call) which will use them to generate cropped image. Read more here: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_API.html .

Then, your PHP script has to read coords from POST data and process the image file. You can see an example of such script here: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html .